# "Expected primary-expression" compilation error when going from VS2012 to gcc (cygwin)

Tags: c++

I am trying to get a C++ code which used to compile fine in Visual Studio 2012
to compile under g++ in the cygwin environment.

```
template<typename M, typename V, typename E, typename F, typename H>
void _input_traits( M * pMesh )
{
    if( M->m_input_traits |= VERTEX_UV )
    {
        _read_vertex_uv<M,V,E,F,H>( pMesh );
    }
};
```

gcc produces the following errors

> In file included from
>   MeshLib/algorithm/MapperMesh.h:27:0,
>                    from main.cpp:10: MeshLib/core/Parser/traits_io.h: In function ‘void MeshLib::_input_traits(M*)’:
>   MeshLib/core/Parser/traits_io.h:367:7: error: expected
>   primary-expression before ‘->’ token   if( M->m_input_traits |=
>   VERTEX_UV )

What primary expression is gcc talking about?

Comment: Isn't M a type? You can not deref a type. And I would believe that this code did not compile in VS as well...

Comment: There is no way this compiled in VS. It's completely nonsensical!

Comment: _"What primary expression is gcc talking about?"_ It's a reference to grammar productions. C++ can't parse your nonsense code (or figure out what you meant instead), so it's just telling you what grammar production it expected next. The best clue here is that a typename is basically never an "expression", whereas only an expression can feed into an operator.

Answer (score 2):

In `M->m_input_traits |= VERTEX_UV` shouldn't `M` be `pMesh` instead?\

M is the type while pMesh is the pointer that you want to use.